# How to custom url without change resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Our website is rails 4.2.8 and ruby 2.4.1, we have products to sell, so our routes like:

```
resources :products 
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
        collection do
          get :success
          get :fail
          get :details
        end
```

so orders url like: https://example.com/orders/new?params...

but we want add product name on url for tracking purpose, something like:

https://example.com/**product_name**/orders/new?params...

can I accomplish this without change route resources or controller position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, No you cannot..
You have to define such nested routes in your `routes.rb` which will change the `paths` and so all dependencies needs to be changed..

To be honest,

`https://example.com/product_name/orders/new?params` this url doesn't make sense to me..
Ideally, correct me if I am wrong, your `order` must be having `has_many` relation with the `products`. However, the url conveys different story...

Comment: yeh... thanks for your response, In fact, we want do change url like: .../product_name/... is to match Facebook Pixel API for different tracking purpose, so we can set something like: /example.com/product_name/* to trace, as an engineer, I know this change will make code in a mess, so we try to find different way...

Comment: Can you make use of params?

Comment: This API seems just track url.

Comment: Atleast you can replace existing product urls having id with names safely using friendly_id gem

Comment: Yes, we already use friendly_id gem, but we want to show both product_name and orders related action in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the routes like:

```
resources :products do
    resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] do
        collection do
          get :success
          get :fail
          get :details
    end
end
```

Then you will get the route
https://example.com/product_name/orders/new?params...